# Go imports saving and unsaving multiple times

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, when the golang code is saved, the imports misbehave by saving and undoing save multiple times until it finally settles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `"groupImports.onSave": false` to the `settings.json` file which can be found in ***.vscode*** folder.

To apply this change just to your user workspace, open the *user settings* by typing **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **P** and select the **User** tab. Search for `groupImport` and uncheck the ***Automatically group imports on save*** checkbox.